# What is the type of `this` object in solidity

Tags: solidity

In the following `claimPayment` function that is used to claim a payment made earlier to this contract, the line `bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, amount, nonce, this)));` has `this` as part of the signed message. This makes me wonder what is `this` and what the type of `this` is. If I'm returning `this` in a function, what type is used for it? Thanks.

```
    function claimPayment(uint256 amount, uint256 nonce, bytes memory signature) public {
        require(!usedNonces[nonce]);
        usedNonces[nonce] = true;

        // this recreates the message that was signed on the client
        bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, amount, nonce, this)));

        require(recoverSigner(message, signature) == owner);

        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the current class instance, as in many other programming languages. You can for example point to public methods:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        this.bar();
    }
    
    function bar() public {
    }
}
```

When `this` is typecasted, it takes a form of the address, where the current instance is deployed.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external view returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodePacked(this);
    }
    
    function bar() external view returns (address) {
        return address(this);
    }
}
```

[image: Typecasting example screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I later figured that out. Interestingly, it was used for a different purpose to silence state mutabilit warning. But it was fixed though.